# How do you specify the type of file you're looking for in an 'open file' dialog with a pattern?

Tags: applications, file, dialog

On every other operating system except MacOS, when you bring up an Open File dialog, you can type (for example) `*.txt` or even `*recipe*.txt` to narrow down the list shown on the screen.

On MacOS, there's just a predefined list of filename extensions that you can choose from, but I don't see anywhere to type a file match pattern myself. I want to filter by the whole filename, not just the extension. How do I enable this very basic feature that I take for granted on both Windows and Linux?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The answer is that only partial functionality is available via Spotlight. If the file you're looking for is anywhere in the Unix-style directories such as `/tmp`, `/etc`, `/usr`, `/var`, etc, Apple's Open dialog is just broken and you simply cannot filter your view of the files there except by a predetermined set of file extensions.

Comment: This 'rant' is kind of like complaining that you can't edit source code with Microsoft Word.  Each app has it's intended purpose.  Mac provides a better experience by not giving users a 'kitchen sink' of menu options with every app like Windows.

Comment: The Mac experience has always been terrible, but at least nowadays they can run Emacs, bash, and other Unix tools. My employer wouldn't be a Mac shop otherwise.

Comment: @ThrowawayAccount3Million it's not broken.  It filters those directories out because the audience are not people who want to see what's in those folders.  Many things on the macOS are filtered out, obfuscated or otherwise hidden in order to reduce clutter and make it better for the ideal audience.  That audience is clearly not you, however, coming from your background there are ways you can make the macOS work well for you.  You may just need to be less rigid about it.  I say that not in a condescending way but from my own personal experience.

Comment: @demianturner It's more like complaining that my car doesn't have a "reverse" gear because the engineers took into account the fact that people are more interested in driving forward. That's literally how Macs are designed. I don't even have the luxury of an escape key unless I plug in an external keyboard. Other manufacturer's laptops not only have escape, but they also have Home, End, PageUp, and PageDown, and unlike the case in macOS, they actually work.

Comment: @ThrowawayAccount3Million I'm not kidding. The people who buy Macs generally appreciate them. I'll certified across platforms, I've used Linux for 15+ years, MS for the same and Macs for even longer, and my daily machine is a Mac because it does certain things in a way I appreciate much more than the other platforms do. Sorry you've had bad experiences but that doesn't mean the product is bad, it just means it doesn't meet your expectations.

Answer (score 4):

You have Spotlight available from every file-picker dialog.

[image]

You can search by name or extension/file type, either in the currently open directory or the entire machine.

[image]

<sup>Sidebar hidden to save unnecessary extraneous detail</sup>

If you know the name rather than the filetype of the document you are looking for, then, same as in any Finder folder, you can start to type the name & the selection will jump to the first match for that string.

eg typing t,e,s will find the first match on test.txt, but you can't use this to find a file type .xml etc as it only searches from the beginning of the name.

[image]

Comment: I have several files in `/tmp` with "category" in the name, and this approach isn't matching any of them. Spotlight defaults to searching "This Mac", which shows all kinds of irrelevant crap, and if I click "tmp", I see no results, even though the files in question are right there.

Comment: Spotlight doesn't search 'hidden' folders.

Comment: I'm looking to search "the current folder", whatever that may be. Spotlight is useless.

Comment: OK, answer updated for secondary method.

Comment: The secondary method (also supported on Linux and Windows) only applies if you know what the filename *begins* with. I may have a file named `467de3a7f-category-id-3722983.csv`. On a real operating system I'd enter the pattern `*category*` and be done with it. Apparently, the answer under MacOS is to read the name of every file in the directory until you see the one you're looking for.

Comment: I'm sorry the answer you got wasn't the one you wished you could have. That doesn't make it wrong. We're here to answer your questions; your frustration is all your own.

Comment: The correct answer appears to be "there's no way to do that on MacOS because MacOS is faulty by design." Whoever posts that will have their answer accepted.

Comment: I refer you to my previous comment. Please do not take your frustration out on me, I was trying to help. I shall try not to make the mistake of doing that again.

Answer (score 0):

Following the example screens provided by Tetsujin, immediately prior to entering text in search area, it would be possible to use the Finder menu to Go : Go to Folder... and then enter **/tmp** in the dialogue box shown. Thereafter entering text in the Search field should find the files of interest.

[image]

Comment: There is no Finder menu if the Open dialog was created by another app. You might as well have suggested using the `open` command from the shell.

Comment: @ThrowawayAccount3Million use cmd-shift-g, that pulls up the 'Go to Folder' dialog.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example using a standard Open dialog, specifying `text` files which are really just any non-binary files, and then doing a `contains` search so you're not limited to prefixes.

[image]
[image]

### Update

The above doesn't work in `/tmp` because Spotlight doesn't index hidden folders.  So just use `grep` at the command line.

[image]

Comment: That doesn't work in `/tmp/`. As I already said, Spotlight is useless.

Comment: That's because Spotlight doesn't search in hidden folders. I refer you back to my answer & comments.

Comment: I can confirm this doesn't work in /tmp, I was surprised, Tetsujin's explanation sounds reasonable.  I would argue if you know what `/tmp` is you should know what `grep` is.

Comment: I do know what `grep` is, but if I already have a GUI app open, I want to be able to easily open my file from within it, like I can under Linux. That a Unix-like server OS is easier and more pleasant to use than the Mac is not a point in Apple's favor.

Comment: @ThrowawayAccount3Million it isn't Linux, it's not going to behave exactly the same as Linux does.  I understand the frustration but you'll need to accept this as a limitation; what you want is simply not built-in to the OS the way you want it to be.

Answer (score -1):

You can access any folder from any file dialog box by pressing cmd-shift-g and entering the directory path.  This is the same as "Go to folder..." in the Finder.  Then enter your search parameters in the search box.
[image: Open file dialog box from within Safari]

Comment: Yes, this is how I got to `/tmp` in the first place. Thanks for pointing out the obvious. If you search for `passwd` while you're poking around in `/etc` you'll discover that the search tool can't find it because it's deliberately crippled.